# REPLACE INTO vs Update

Tags: php, mysql

I recently found the MYSQL function `REPLACE INTO`, so it got the ball rolling in comparison to `INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE`.. When shall I use `REPLACE INTO` over the other used functions? 
When is it acceptable to use replace into over Update into

Standard procedure for my current update would be:

1. Check user input exits
2. Query the database that the rows exist
3. Update row

Standard procedure for my inserts would be

1. Check User input exists
2. Check if row exists
3. If not then insert
4. If not then return an error

So, overall. `REPLACE INTO` vs `UPDATE`. When acceptable, pros and cons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace was designed to ease the following case:

1. Check, if record with same PK exists
2. If yes, delete the row and insert a new row for the record with the given one
3. If no, insert a new record

As per documentation REPLACE is equivalent to INSERT, apart from deleting any existing record having the PK is beeing deleted before.

Comment: #2 is not entirely correct. It doesn't `UPDATE` but `DELETE + INSERT` a row

Comment: Yes, technically it will do DELETE+INSERT. I only wanted to describe the use case.

Comment: what "that's"? "If yes, update the record with the given one" statement is incorrect

Comment: @db-mobile: it still need some rewording, since it may confuse one and lead to data loss

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE INTO` should best be thought of as a conditional insert.  It will look at the primary/unique keys for the record being inserted, and if one of those unique keys already exists, it will update the value for the existing record rather than insert. This update is done via deletion of the old row and insert of new row data.

So really what this does is allow you to get away from having to check that a certain primary/unique key may already exist before trying an insert (which would normally result in error).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the user an error when something like this occurs, go for method 2 you described! Otherwise, if it doesn't matter if it already exists in the database and you just want to replace the record, use the first method you described!

Comment: The methodology is just for an example, overall the question is the pros and cons and an acceptable time on when to use `REPLACE INTO`

Comment: I would say, `REPLACE` is a shorthand. Otherwise you'll have to do it with at least 2 queries. Use it when you need it.